# Como salvar dados Console Application usando EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, console

Fiz uma aplicação console usando o `Entity Framework`, só que estou tendo dificuldades para implementar os métodos da minha classe de repositório que herda de uma interface,fiz minhas classes de interface e minha classe concreta de repositório dessa maneira:

```
public interface IBaseRepositorio<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    //Métodos para obter todos contatos e obter por Id
    List<Contato> ObterTodosContatos();
    Contato ObterContatoId(int id);

    //Métodos de inserção,atualização,exclusão
    bool IncluirContato(Contato contato);
    bool AtualizarContato(Contato contato, String colunaAtual);
    bool DeletarContato(int id);
}
```

Minha InterfaceBase.

Aqui minha Interface que herda da Interface base:

```
 public interface IContatoRepositorio:IBaseRepositorio<Contato>
 {

 }
```

Mas aqui na minha classe concreta de repositório eu não consigo realizar as operações para rodar meu CRUD,segue a classe:

```
public class ContatoRepositorio : IContatoRepositorio<Contato>
{
    protected ProjectTestsContext Db = new ProjectTestsContext();


    public Contato ObterContatoId(int id)
    {
        return this.Db.Contatos.SqlQuery("Select * From Contato where Contatoid = @Contatoid", new { Id = id }).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public List<Contato> ObterTodosContatos()
    {
        return this.Db.Contatos.SqlQuery("Select * From Contatos").ToList();
    }

    public bool IncluirContato(Contato contato)
    {
        try
        {
            string sql = "INSERT INTO Contato(Nome,Sobrenome,Empresa,Titulo) values(@Nome,@Sobrenome,@Empresa,@Titulo);SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int)";
            var returnId = Db.Contatos.SqlQuery(sql, contato).SingleOrDefault();
            contato.Contatoid = returnId.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public bool AtualizarContato(Contato contato, string colunaAtual)
    {
        string query = "Update Contato set " + colunaAtual + " =@" + colunaAtual + "Where Contatoid=@Contatoid";
        var count = Db.Execute(query, contato);
        return true;

    }

    public bool DeletarContato(int id)
    {
        // var affectdrowns = Db.Execute("Delete From Contato where Contatoid = @Contatoid", new { Contatoid = id });
        //   return affectdrowns > 0;
        return true;
    }



}
```

No método de atualizar contato, o trecho Db.Execute, não acha a ação que ele teria que fazer,achei somente o Entry,mas não consigo fazer a atualização.

Se alguém puder me ajudar como realizar da melhor maneira esses métodos,agradeço,até para eu dar sequência no raciocínio.

Obrigado

Comment: você esta criando seu DbSet ?no seu ProjectTestsContext

Answer (score 0):

Se você tive criado seus [DbSet](https://github.com/MarconcilioSouza/Projetos/blob/master/Projeto_Modelo/ProjetoModelo.Infra.Data.EF/Contexto/DBContexto.cs), você pode criar um CRUD mais simples com o Entity Framework.

Veja como ficaria.

```
public class ContatoRepositorio : IContatoRepositorio<Contato>
{
    protected ProjectTestsContext Db = new ProjectTestsContext();


    public Contato ObterContatoId(int id)
    {
        return this.Db.Contatos.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id = id );
    }

    public List<Contato> ObterTodosContatos()
    {
        return this.Db.Contatos.ToList();
    }

    public bool IncluirContato(Contato contato)
    {
        try
        {
            Db.Contato.Add(contato);
            Db.SaveChanges();   
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public bool AtualizarContato(Contato contato, string colunaAtual)
    {
        Db.Entry(contato).State = EntityState.Modified;
        Db.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }

    public bool DeletarContato(int id)
    {
        var obj = ObterContatoId(id);
        Db.Categorias.Remove(obj);
        Db.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Veja um exemplo funcional [aqui](https://github.com/MarconcilioSouza/LojaVirtual/blob/master/LojaVirtual.Infra.Data.EF/Repositorios/RepositorioCategorias.cs).